# How to build a jar file with an icon for the tray?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, tray

I'm building an application to run in the tray. Of course, it has to display an icon in the tray, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.

When I compile myself in IntelliJ, it all works nicely, but when I build the jar file it doesn't display the correct icon.

This is my code responsible for adding the icon

```
 Image img =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/main/resources/bsx.png");
 TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "Loop Driver", popupMenu);

 trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
 trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popupMenu);

 try{
   systemTray.add(trayIcon);
 } catch (AWTException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
 }
```

when I compile in IntelliJ I have the icon I want in the tray

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42PE0.png)

but when I build jar file I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGKLb.png)

In Project Structure I have that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su7MS.png)

what am I doing wrong?

I try many solution and configuration but nothing work.

Comment: Use `ImageIO` to load your image and as a resource, not a file. Use URL `"/bsx.png"`

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources: [Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans) [Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: `src` won't exist at runtime. From the looks of it, you're using Maven, so you should start by using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/bsx.png"))`.  This can throw an exception (if the image can't be found/loaded) unlike most methods which fail silently

Comment: ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/bsx.png")) work for me.